# DBT + Databricks -> Specify cluster for a test

Tags: databricks, dbt

When I run generic dbt commands (such as `dbt debug`), my [project defaults](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/python-models#specific-data-platforms) to using the `all_purpose_cluster` defined in my connection profile.

When I execute `dbt test --select a_big_model`, my test utilizes the `all_purpose_cluster` which is too small for the computation – this causes my tests to fail because of resource issues. **Is there a way for me to configure a specific cluster to be used when I run tests on a specific model?**

**Brainstorming:**

- Possible solution could be to use a different profile for "big" or "small" tests. But I'd rather define that in the model config (or project config, under schema), instead of command line.
- Another idea is to define `submission_method` for a given model's tests in my `dbt_project.yml`, though I'm not convinced this will work...

Answer (score 1):

You can [override default configs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/model-configs) for individual model files via `config blocks`.

In Databricks the `http_path` can be specified to switch the cluster used to run the model.

Note: For Databricks, this is only available in python models.

```py
def model(dbt, _):
   dbt.config(
       materialized='table',
       http_path='...'
   )
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when running tests